# Spring data rest override nested property POST handler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have a Spring Data Rest repository

```java
public interface ProjectRepository extends CrudRepository<Project, Integer> {}
```

for the following entity:

```java
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "project", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"owner_id", "title"})})
public class Project {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "project_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    ...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "project_document", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "document_id",
                    nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    private Set<Document> documents;

    ...
}
```

I want to override the POST handler of the nested `documents` collection and am following the [recommended approach](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers).

```java
@RepositoryRestController
public class DocumentController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/projects/{projectId}/documents", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Document postDocument(
            final @PathVariable int projectId,
            final @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile documentFile,
            final @RequestPart("description") String description
    ) throws IOException {
        ...
    }
}
```

But when I fire up the nested POST, it still uses the original Spring generated POST handler and throws unsupported media-type error.

When I change `@RepositoryRestController` to `@RestController`, the correct POST handler is used, but the Spring generated CRUD methods for `documents` subresource of `project` are not exported.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("/projects/{id}")
public class ProjectsController {

    private final @NonNull DocumentRepository documentRepository;

    @PostMapping("/documents")
    public ResponseEntity<?> postDocument(@PathVariable("id") Project project, @RequestBody Document document) {
        if (project == null) {
            throw new Exception("Project is not found!");
        }

        if (document == null) {
            throw new Exception("Document is not found");
        }

        Document savedDocument = documentRepository.save(document.setProject(project));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new Resource<>(savedDocument), CREATED);
    }
}
```

Working [example](https://github.com/Cepr0/restvotes/blob/master/src/main/java/restvotes/rest/controller/RestaurantController.java).